# scale/transform image in a dialog on load

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a need to show a dialog with a map in it.  The map will be somewhat small on smaller devices and only part of the map needs to be visible.  I'd like to have the map load and then zoom and move to a predefined point based on which part of the map I need to show.  So far I have this:

```
class RegionMap extends StatelessWidget {
  const RegionMap({
    Key key,
    @required this.region,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final RegionMapping region;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.white,
      elevation: 4,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          ClipRect(
            child: Transform.scale(
              scale: region.imageZoomScale,
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              origin: region.imageOffset,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Image.asset('assets/us_map.png'),
                  Image.asset(
                      'assets/regions_indv/${region.regionCode}.png'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(thickness: 2),          
          Text('${region.regionFullName}',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: textSize,
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

which produces this output:

[image: output]

What I am struggling with is the right combination of animations and or transforms to get what I want.  No matter what I set the Offset too it shows the same section of the map.  Any thoughts on the right combination of things to get what I'm looking for?

Comment: Try with changing `alignment` of `Transform`. Also you can increase the image size and positioned it in stack, use `ClipRect` to clip the widget.

Comment: check [Image.alignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/alignment.html) official docs - they say: *"To display a subpart of an image, consider using a CustomPainter and Canvas.drawImageRect."* - it seems like a good advice as you want not only show a subpart of an image but also scale it

Comment: So my offset was working but because of my setup it only picks up the change on restart (not on hot reload).  I was already inside a stack and a ClipRect as my code showed...by what I need to get working now is the zoom, which I believe means I'll need to replace the Translate.scale() with a transition animation of some sort.